# Which GrantTypes to use in IdentityServer4?

Tags: identityserver4

I am using IdentityServer 4 with ASP.NET Core 1.1 and Angular 2.

I need to access the API from 3 different sources:

1. A mobile application;
2. An angular 2 application which is contained on a ASP.NET Core MVC;
3. In the ASP.NET Core MVC controllers.

Which GrantTypes should I use for each one?

Comment: does this help: https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/release/topics/grant_types.html - If no - how can we improve it?

Comment: @leastprivilege I have been reading your docs. May I give a suggestion to improve it? How about having a section with an example on how to test the access to an API with a common tool like Postman and Hybrid flow for example? And then a list of common mistakes people do that could be updated along the way with common questions in Stack Overflow? That would be a good way for people to have some help on testing and finding common mistakes even before going to StackOverflow. Does it make sense?

Comment: We accept PRs for the docs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The API itself doesn't have a GrantType, rather it simply consumes tokens (JWT or Reference).

1. For a mobile application, the usual security concerns of securing credentials in a client-side app applies. In other words, a flow which doesn't require a client secret, and ideally, doesn't give the user the actual access token. Authorization Code / Hybrid Flow meets this criteria. The limitation of this approach is all communication would need to be proxied through the server hosting the access token.
2. Since it is contained in ASP.NET, cookies are an option. Implicit Flow or Authorization Code / Hybrid Flow would work well here. Use Authorization/Hybrid if you need access to refresh tokens.
3. Same as #2

For more detail, Auth0 has a great guide:
https://auth0.com/docs/api-auth/which-oauth-flow-to-use

Answer (score 1):

In reverse order...

**3**. **Authorization Code** (because your secret doesn't leave an environment that you trust)

**2**. **Implicit** (because your code **does** leave an environment you trust - i.e. runs on the client's browser, so any secret would be accessible)

**1**. For me, **implicit**, because you can't really trust the mobile environment (i.e. the code could be reviewed and your secret compromised). However, you could use authorization code, but if you do, your mobile secret should be different from the MVC secret.

You could also consider **Hybrid** for the MVC & mobile flow, as that will use server to server communication for the access token exchange.